# How are fcgi scripts tested?

Tags: testing, fastcgi, meson-build

I am a newbie so forgive me if this sounds naive. I wrote a script in fastcgi++. And I tested the basic use cases. But like a good software engineer I want to test the script every time I make a change to make sure I don't break things.

This was what I used to do:

This was my directory structure:

```
script:

 - bin 
 - build (contained the bash script to compile the script)
 - src
 - tests  
    - build (contained bash script to compile the test)
    - src (contained the test file)
    - output
```

I hacked the way I tested. I used to use curl to call my script and redirect its output to a file in tests/output (using relative path) and compare it with the expected output. I could do that because the tests were compiled by hand and I only executed the tests after changing the directory to `tests/build`. I recently decided to use a build system. I chose meson. The way you test using meson is by running `meson test` or `ninja test`. The problem is now I do not control from where the test is run.

How to test in such circumstance? And how you test your fcgi scripts?

**Edit:** This is an example of how I was compiling and testing. This is a complete verifyable example:

```
#include <fastcgi++/request.hpp>
#include <fastcgi++/manager.hpp>

class test : public Fastcgipp::Request<char> 
{
    bool response() {
        nlohmann::json output;

        out << "Content-Type: application/json; charset:utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        out << "{\"success\": true}";
    }
}

int main() {
    Fastcgipp::Manager<test> manager;

    manager.setupSignals();
    manager.listen();
    manager.start();
    manager.join();
}
```

You can think of response as the main. This is where you start processing things. You can take input and output and all that good stuff.

This is how I am testing:

```
TEST(test, test1) {

    std::string fileName = "test.txt";

    nlohmann::json input, output;
    input["success"] = true;

    std::system(std::string("curl -X GET \"localhost/cgi-bin/test.fcg\" > " + fileName).c_str());

    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    std::string out;
    std::getline(file, out);

    output = nlohmann::json::parse(out);

    ASSERT_EQ(input, output);

    std::system(std::string("rm " + fileName).c_str());
}
```

**Notes:** nlohmann::json is a json parser and I am using google test in the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is now I do not control from where the test is run.

The test by default is run in the build directory, but there is parameter **workdir** (see [reference](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#test)) that you can use to set *absolute path that will be used as the working directory for the test*, for example:

```
exe = executable(...)
wdir = join_paths(meson.current_source_dir(), 'some_dir')
test('basic', exe, workdir : wdir)
```

Check [meson object](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#meson-object) for other possible reference directories.

Comment: So is this how fcgi has been tested or is there a better way?

Comment: @Hemil better is very vague criteria, in what way better? If you use meson for building that make perfect sense to use meson to run tests, I think. If you have specific question about how to test program or script - welcome to provide more specific example.

Comment: I was used to testing by calling a function and checking its return value. Reading from files seemed odd to me ;P

Comment: @Hemil Thanks for accepting, if you want better advice - can you show example how you build and test, because I don't understand what is "reading from files" related to

Comment: Check the question now and let me know if you need more details

Comment: @Hemil I suggest you to learn some basics about unit testing, you have something that looks like functional test. It's fine if you're fine and it helps you to make sure changes are safe. However you can't validate every aspect of implemented C++ class or C module. The main difference is that you link against your lib or program module and trial some public method with valid and invalid inputs to check later that you have expected results. I found some unit test related to fastcgi, take a look: https://github.com/crnt/Fastcgi-Daemon/blob/master/tests/test_request.cpp

Comment: Ik the basics of unit test. My problem is, as of now, the scripts are too small to be further broken into independent parts  (maybe a 100-150 lines of code in each script). Like all I am doing is checking if the parameters are correct, running a database query and returning JSON. I can't think of a way to unit test this